# How to solve this equation in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis

So I need to find all $z$ $\in \mathbb{C}$ that are a solution to the equation:

$$\operatorname{Re}\left(\frac{z-a}{z-b}\right) = 0$$
 knowing that $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$

I have no idea where to start, any help is appreciated.

Comment: i see no equation here

Comment: I'm sorry about that, got so worried writing everything in Latex that I forgot to add the rest

Comment: Have you tried to solve it by putting $z=x+iy$ ?

Comment: Yes I have, I probably should've mentioned that a and b are complex numbers too, I'll add that right now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way to approach this problem is geometrically.  $\frac{z-a}{z-b} = \frac{a-z}{b-z}$ is a pure imaginary if $a-z$ (treated as a vector from the origin) is perpendicular to $b-z$.  But note that $a-z$ can be thought of as a vector from $z$ (instead of the origin) to $a$; likewise, $b-z$ is equivalent to a vector from $z$ to $b$.

In other words, the solution space consists of those points $z$ on the complex plane such that $\triangle azb$, so to speak, is a right triangle with the right angle at $z$.  [But this is simply the circle whose diameter is $a$ to $b$](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Thales%27_Theorem), removing the point $b$ itself, for which the original fraction is undefined.

[image]

There is a degenerate case if $a = b$, in which case the solution space is empty.

Comment: Why does purely imaginary follow from the ratio of vectors orthogonal to each other?

Comment: @GFauxPas: When you multiply a complex number by $i$, you effectively rotate it by $90$ degrees counter-clockwise in the complex plane.  The property of perpendicularity is unaffected by scaling (including negative scaling).

Comment: I think I get it. We can say $\frac{z-a}{z-b} \propto i \iff (z-a) \propto e^{i\pi/2}(z-b) \iff (z-a)\perp(z-b)$?

Comment: Well, yes.  I'm not exactly sure why that helps you see it, but if so, good!

Comment: Different minds think in different ways!

Comment: @GFauxPas: They do indeed!

Answer (score 2):

I would start with $\frac{z-a}{z-b}=ci$ for some $c \in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

The LHS is a Moebius transformation applied to z. So your solution set will be the image of the imaginary axis under the inverse of that transformation (think matrices modulo their determinant to invert easily). Three points will determine its location completely, as it must be a straight line or circle.